# How to send 20 packets using ping or any other command in Packet tracer?

Tags: ping, packet-tracer

Is there any command to send 20 packets per second. I have one switch and two hosts. M looking to send 20 packets within seconds, for stats of Latency. I am using packet tracer 6.2.  I want to ping 192.168.1.30 to 192.168.1.40 ,and there is switch between them.

Comment: This question sounds likea homework question which is off-topic for Network Engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using GNU/Linux to send the ping:

```
ping -i 0.05 <target ip>
```

Comment: i am using Packet tracer, please tell me command for PT

Comment: So you mean Cisco's packet tracer? As far as I'm aware, it doesn't have this capability.